# BizTalk SourceFileName becomes dehydrated

Tags: biztalk

I'm trying to use a custom filename since i need to create two files (a backupfile) so i followed the following tutorial to create filename [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13449/Using-the-SourceFileName-Macro-to-Create-a-Custom)

now when i test this with `DELCUS%MessageID%.txt` everything works fine but when i change it to `DELCUS%SourceFileName%.txt` the interface becomes permanently dehydrated.

the only thing i do for the filename is this

> fileName = "ContExt" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
>   Message_send_Belspeed_BeautDay_ContExt(FILE.ReceivedFileName) =
>   fileName;

is there any reason why the use of SourceFileName would cause this to dehydrate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the issue.

after a while the interface did crash and the filename looks like

DELCUS2012 10:50:40.txt

having : in a filename is not good.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a standard windows file naming limitation, you can't name your file using any of these characters "\ / : * ? " < > |". So obviously your instances are going to get stuck!!

Comment: Yup, just me not thinking that a System.DateTime.Now.ToString(); would contain the time as a 10:50:40. so i made the tostring have a format in it.